# Sample size - Diagnostic Accuracy Study

Tags: sample-size

We have a gold standard test and a new test, and want to compare them prospectively, in a diagnostic accuracy study. I want to work out the sample size required. I have done some reading, and there is a calculator online:
https://turkjemergmed.com/calculator
However, this asks you to enter the sensitivity and specificity of the new test. I am confused, because the outcome of the diagnostic accuracy study will presumably be sensitivity and specificity as well, presented in a 2x2 contingency table. So the whole exercise seems circular.

Secondly, how do I go about finding the confidence interval of sens/spec? I found another equation online:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK305683/
But it feels like I am just apply random calculations to my numbers, and I am not sure if it is appropriate.

Many thanks for your advice.
Johnny